# Trigger to update parent table based on max value of child table

Tags: t-sql

this is my first foray into SSMS/T-SQL (coming from Access).  I have a trigger setup that keeps the value of a column in a parent table always equal to the MAX value of a column a child table based on the key between them.  To calculate the MAX I have a UDF defined that i Think works ok.

The problem I seem to have is that the trigger executes for EVERY key in the table and not just the one that got updated/deleted/inserted (or so is what I can glean from the debugger).

Here is the parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[factMeasures](
    [MeasureID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QARTOD] [int] NULL,
    [Param] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [real] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_factMeasures] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MeasureID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here is the child table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dt_QCflags](
    [QC_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fkMeasureID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RuleValue] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dt_QCflags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QC_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dt_QCflags]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dt_QCflags_factMeasures] FOREIGN KEY([fkMeasureID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[factMeasures] ([MeasureID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dt_QCflags] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dt_QCflags_factMeasures]
GO
```

HEre is the UDF that calculates the MAX value of [RuleValue] for the input [MeasureID]

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MaxQC](@MeasureID INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

RETURN
    (SELECT
      Max([dt_QCflags].[RuleValue]) AS Max_RuleValue
    FROM
      dbo.dt_QCflags
    WHERE
      dt_QCflags.fkMeasureID = @MeasureID
    GROUP BY
      fkMeasureID);

END
```

And here is the trigger on the child table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateQARTOD]
    ON [dbo].[dt_QCflags]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN   
    UPDATE factMeasures
    SET QARTOD = dbo.MaxQC(MeasureID)  -- by QARTOD Definition, QARTOD flag is set to the MAX of all sub-test results

END
```

So what I want is for the column in the parent (factMeasures.QARTOD) to always contain the Maximum of the column in the child table (dt_QCFlags.RuleValue), **for the given MeasureID value**

When I debug this, it seems to be running the trigger for EVERY record in the parent table, so I think I need to modify the trigger, but i"m not sure how to get the MeasureID of JUST the record that was added/deleted/modified.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the "magic tables" inserted, deleted, etc. but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that unless you have a very good reason, storing values that can easily be computed on a query level is a mistake.

This seems like one of many cases I've seen where people think they gain something by storing values on one table that's calculated from values of another table, but in fact the opposite is true - now you have two points of data that needs to be synchronized at all times, and since the process synchronizing them is a trigger, you don't really have control over that - it's quite easy to disable / enable triggers, for instance.

Therefore, **My advice to you would be to remove that trigger all together and simply calculate the value when you need to.**

Please note that since SQL Server supports [`max() over(partition by)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) meaning you don't even need a `group by` if you want to calculate the max of a column.

**Updated** Following your comments to the answer, it seems like you have a good reason to store these values.

Having said all that, here's a direct answer to the question you've asked.
In SQL Server triggers, the database enables you to query two special tables called [`inserted` and `deleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017). These tables contains the data that was (or going to be, in case of `instead of` triggers) inserted or deleted to the table on which the trigger is declared.

Please note that in SQL Server, triggers are fired per statement, not per row. This means that the `inserted` and `deleted` tables might contain 0, 1 or many rows.

If you still want to calculate the value using triggers, I would advise a trigger for insert/update and another trigger for deletes.

This would make for much simpler code.

In the delete trigger, you left join to the `deleted` table:

```
UPDATE T
SET QARTOD = MaxValue
FROM factMeasures As T
JOIN 
(
    SELECT d.fkMeasureID, Max(t.RuleValue) As MaxValue
    FROM Deleted AS d
    LEFT JOIN dt_QCflags As t
        ON d.QC_ID = t.QC_ID
    GROUP BY d.fkMeasureID
) as D
    ON T.MeasureID = D.fkMeasureID
```

In the insert/update trigger, you write a very similar code - but you don't need to refer to the physical table in this case, only the `inserted` table:

```
UPDATE T
SET QARTOD = MaxValue
FROM factMeasures As T
JOIN 
(
    SELECT fkMeasureID, Max(RuleValue) As MaxValue
    FROM Inserted 
    GROUP BY fkMeasureID
) as I
    ON t.MeasureID = I.fkMeasureID
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar, this worked almost perfectly!  Just a few tweaks:
The delete trigger isn't working 100% correctly, I first changed it to `  SELECT DISTINCT fkMeasureID, Max(RuleValue) OVER (PARTITION BY fkMeasureID) as MaxValue
  FROM dt_QCflags
 ) as D` 
because when a child is value is deleted the parent value should be updated to whatever the new (if any) max value is.  However, this still isn't working right in the case of deleting the last child, in that case the parent stays the same as it was, is there a way to update it to NULL?

Comment: re your comment about not using the trigger at all.  I 100% agree, however the design of this db is an OLAP warehouse and the factMeasure table will have millions of rows, but only updated infrequently (~once/year).  Then a separate process runs to update the child table (and the trigger fired to update the parent column), but for reporting purposes only the parent is of interest.  Therefore, I opted to use the trigger strictly for performance reasons.  But, if a child needs to be manually tweaked/modified I want to ensure that the parent is updated WITHOUT the need to run the process again.

Comment: As for the first comment, I forgot the group by clause. Also, in case of a delete trigger, I've also made another mistake - the query has to left join the deleted table with the physical table to get correct result This will also take care of values completely deleted from the physical table. I've edited that into the answer. As for the second comment, well, that is a good reason for storing the aggregated value in the parent table.

Comment: Thanks again Zohar, that worked but I had to make one change to the Delete trigger, I think the join should be on d.fkMeasureID = t.fkMeasureID (not QC_ID).  The way it is above, if a record is deleted in the child it will make the parent NULL, **regardless if there are still other records in the child**.  This fix (i think) fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably correct. I've has a doubt as to which column to use for the join.